# How to match/replace a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, regex-group

I need to delete a part of a string of characters, the problem is that I do not know either the position or the character of beginning, even for the end.

Example 1:

> The source string : image_807x400.jpg
>
> Expected Result : image.jpg

Example 2:

> The source string : image-7x2.jpg
>
> Expected Result : image.jpg

At that moment I found a solution but it takes a lot of time:

```
function replace($output)
{
    $final = array();
    foreach ($output as $table => $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file => $ids) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 9999; $i++) {
                for ($j = 0; $j <= 9999; $j++) {
                    $param = '_' . $i . 'x' . $j . '.';

                    $exist = strpos($file, $param);

                    if (!$exist) {
                        $param = '-' . $i . 'x' . $j . '.';
                        $exist = strpos($file, $param);
                    }

                    if ($exist) {
                        $newFileName = str_replace($param, '.', $file);
                        $final[$table][$file] = $newFileName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $final;
}
```

Comment: You have to have some rules, what would `image2_807x400` be?  How about `2Dimage_01` or `2D-image_01`?

Comment: image2_807x400 => mage2
2Dimage_01 => 2Dimage
2D-image_01 => 2D-image

Comment: Do all the filenames end on `.jpg`?

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: Hello,

No, No,
I've found the solution, Thank You!

/[ _-]\d+x\d+/

Answer (score 0):

For your example data, you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and make use of `\K` to forget what was matched:

```
\w+\K[_-]\d+(?:x\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJVlJ1/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/lSYrb)

For example:

```
$strings = [
    "image_807x400.jpg",
    "image-7x2.jpg",
    "actuality_1x30.jpg",
    "team_1200x800.jpg ",
    "help_504x300.jpg",
    "image2_807x400",
    "2Dimage_01",
    "2D-image_01"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace('/\w+\K[_-]\d+(?:x\d+)?/', '', $string) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
image.jpg
image.jpg
actuality.jpg
team.jpg 
help.jpg
image2
2Dimage
2D-image
```

Comment: What about my list of images like this:
actuality_1x30.jpg
team_1200x800.jpg
help_504x300.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't make sense of all the looping and variable names so just adapt this:

```
$info = pathinfo($file);
preg_match('/^[a-z]+/i', $info['basename'], $match);
$final = $match[0].$info['extension'];
```

- Get the basename
- Match only letters `[a-z]` at the beginning `^`, where `i` means case-insensitive
- Add the extension

Answer (score 0):

This regex might cover your instances by creating two groups, your first partial word and everything else including the extension(s). You may only need to add any other characters except for [a-z] that you might have in your initial first word in your output array.

It may not be the best idea to bound your regex from the right, since you may have `JPG`, `JPEG`, `jpg` and other extensions similar to:

```
$output = array(
    'table1' => array(
        '1' => 'image_807x400.jpg',
        '2' => 'image-7x2.jpg',
        '3' => 'image-7x2.JPEG',
        '4' => 'image-7x2.JPG',
        '5' => 'image-7x2.PNG',
        '6' => 'image_807x400.png',
        '7' => 'image_807x400.gif',
        '8' => 'image_807x400.GIF',
    ),
    'table2' => array(
        '1' => 'image_807x400.jpg',
        '2' => 'image-7x2.jpg',
        '3' => 'image-7x2.JPEG',
        '4' => 'image-7x2.JPG',
        '5' => 'image-7x2.PNG',
        '6' => 'image_807x400.png',
        '7' => 'image_807x400.gif',
        '8' => 'image_807x400.GIF',
    ),
    'table3' => array(
        '1' => 'actuality_1x30.jpg',
        '2' => 'help_504x300.jpg',
        '3' => 'team_1200x800.jpg',
    ),
);

replace($output);

function replace($output)
{
    $final = array();
    foreach ($output as $table => $files) {
        foreach ($files as $file => $ids) {
            $final[$table][$file] = preg_replace('/(?:^|(?:\.\s))([a-z]+)(.*)/s', '$1.jpg', $output[$table][$file]);
        }
    }
    var_dump($final);
    return $final;
}
```

#### Output

```
array(3) {
  ["table1"]=>
  array(8) {
    [1]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
  }
  ["table2"]=>
  array(8) {
    [1]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [7]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
    [8]=>
    string(9) "image.jpg"
  }
  ["table3"]=>
  array(3) {
    [1]=>
    string(13) "actuality.jpg"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "help.jpg"
    [3]=>
    string(8) "team.jpg"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution:

```
$newFileName = preg_replace('/\K[_-]\d+x\d+/', '', $file);
```

Comment: You don't need the `\K` because you are not matching anything before it.